# How to `AcquireTokenAsync` with netstandard1.3 ADAL, which has no GetCoreUIParent?

Tags: adal

I'm trying to call `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync` to acquire an auth token, using the netstandard1.3 version of the v4 preview library. It fails with a `NotImplementedException`, because "[NetStandard1.3 does not have UI](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/eb3e015c74f8d4c8ca218d076c9e5ab6131bf6ad/adal/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/Platforms/netstandard1.3/PlatformParameters.cs#L38)".

Unfortunately I don't see a way around this: the callstack goes through `AcquireTokenCommonAsync`, which calls `CreateWebAuthenticationDialog`, which calls `GetCoreUIParent`, which is an internal method, not overridable, so it doesn't seem like it's possible to do this at all. What's the plan here?

Full stack:

```
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters.GetCoreUIParent()
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.CreateWebAuthenticationDialog(PlatformParameters parameters)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenCommonAsync(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters
parameters, UserIdentifier userId, String extraQueryParameters, String claims)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters parameters)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
```

Comment: This document should provide some insight. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-2-released